# MapKit - How to get accurate initial reading when first ones are off > 1000 meters sometimes?

Tags: iphone, ios4, mapkit

As I've been playing with MapKit, I've noticed that when my application first launches I have drawn lines all over the place (I'm doing GPS tracking) which shows the initial readings have been way off.

My MapKit is implemented in it's own *MapViewController* and everything is initialized in the *viewDidLoad* method (ie. [locationManager startUpdatingLocation:YES])

Is there a good practice / method though where in the viewDidLoad you can fire off some ActionSheet or something which determines the your location to the best possible accuracy initially before presenting the map and your current location?

Answer (score 1):

Don't draw a line until the location is returned with an accuracy narrower than half the width of the lines your app will be drawing.  Or make the lines much fatter until.

Also, check the time stamp on the locations to make sure that they are recent ones.